# rails 3 migration error in change_column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, migrate, dbmigrate

I am trying to change a column type and getting error. My model is `Conf`, and column name is `xml`. I want to change it from `:file` to `:binary`. `xml` at first created as `text`, then I've changed it to `file` with a similar migration file very much like this one. I want to do the same thing again and change the type to `binary` but getting error.

There is migration file:

```
class ChangeConfXmlColumnToBinary < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :confs, :xml, :binary
  end

  def down
    change_column :confs, :xml, :file
  end
end
```

and this is error:

```
==  ChangeConfXmlColumnToBinary: migrating ====================================
-- change_column(:confs, :xml, :binary)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:229:in `column'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in copy_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:500:in `each'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:500:in `block in copy_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:498:in `copy_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:488:in `move_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:481:in `block in alter_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:480:in `alter_table'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:441:in `change_column'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/home/staj/rails_projects/sample_app/db/migrate/20130826113731_change_conf_xml_column_to_binary.rb:3:in `up'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/staj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`rake db:rollback` gives the same error with "`-- change_column(:confs, :xml, :text)`" at the beginning

Comment: you are using `mysql` or `postgresql`?

Comment: make sure the database you are using supports binary datatype

Comment: @Salil that is sqllite

Comment: I guess Sqlite does not support Binary datatype. Check the list of datatypes supported by Sqlite http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I want to upload .xml files. I tried to convert :blob rather than :binary but get the same error

Comment: ok, i finally figure it out, left it as file and used paperclip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "binary" is a reserved word.
Take a look at this [list of reserve words](http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/).

The word "binary" is a reserved word in both [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) & [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so if you plan on using any of these in production you're likely to run into problems.

Comment: @8bithero, I am using sqllite